# coq: A left-recursive notation must have an explicit level

Tags: coq, notation

I have seen a Coq notation definition for "evaluates to" as follows:

```
Notation "e '||' n" := (aevalR e n) : type_scope.
```

I am trying to change the symbol `'||'` to something else as `||` is often times used for logical `or`. However, I always get an error

```
 A left-recursive notation must have an explicit level
```

For example, this happens when I change `'||'` to:

`'\|/'`, `'\||/'`, `'|_|'`,  `'|.|'`, `'|v|'`, or `'|_'`.

Is there something special about `||` here? and how should I fix it to make these other notations work (if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am right, if you overload a notation, Coq uses the properties of the first definition. The notation `_ '||' _` has already a level, so Coq uses this level for your definition.

But with new symbols, Coq cannot do that, and you have to specify the level:

```
Notation "e '|.|' n" := (aevalR e n) (at level 50) : type_scope.
```

For already defined notations, this is even stronger than what I wrote above. You cannot redefine the level of a notation. Try for example:

```
Notation "e '||' n" := (aevalR e n) (at level 20) : type_scope.
```